# A small C WinAPI program moving the cursor in a circle

Tags: c, winapi

So the program below will move the mouse cursor in a circle all 360 degrees for 2,5 seconds (after 2,5 seconds, the program exits and the user can use his/her cursor normally).

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>

const double RADIANS_PER_DEGREE = acos(-1.0) / 180.0; // acos(-1.0) = Pi
const int SLEEP_DURATION = 2500 / 360;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                      HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                      LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                      int       nCmdShow)
{
    const int screenWidth  = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    const int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    const int screenCenterX = screenWidth  / 2;
    const int screenCenterY = screenHeight / 2;

    const int radius = 3 * min(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2) / 4;
    int currentDegree = 90;

    for (int degree = 0; degree < 360; degree++, currentDegree++) {
        const int x = screenCenterX + (int)(radius * cos(currentDegree * RADIANS_PER_DEGREE));
        const int y = screenCenterY - (int)(radius * sin(currentDegree * RADIANS_PER_DEGREE));

        SetCursorPos(x, y);
        Sleep(SLEEP_DURATION);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Critique request**

I would like to hear anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Integer math for an integer problem**

Consider a variation on [Bresenham's circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) for an integer only solution: faster and precise.

Note: Graphics processors use integer math for drawing circles on a screen, not floating point.

**1 degree steps**?

On high precision monitors, (think 2k * 2k or more) the result may look more circular (not a polygon) with finer steps.  Above integer solution provides the best digitized circle.

**Not standard C code**

Good idea to use the systems best machine π, yet `double global_variable =  some_function(-1.0)` is not valid.  I suspect OP is not using a standard C compiler.

Alternative.  Since π does not change, let the system derive the best *machine π* by providing code that the compiler will use even if `double` is many more than 64-bit.

```
// const double RADIANS_PER_DEGREE = acos(-1.0) / 180.0; // acos(-1.0) = Pi
const double RADIANS_PER_DEGREE = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971  / 180.0;
```

Or define it

```
#ifdef M_PI // some implementation will define this, use if available.
  #define MY_PI M_PI
#else
  #define MY_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971
#endif

const double RADIANS_PER_DEGREE = MY_PI / 180.0;
```

Pedantically, in rare cases, performing math like `MY_PI / 180.0` will **not** result in the best `RADIANS_PER_DEGREE` and code could directly use

```
const double RADIANS_PER_DEGREE = 0.01745329251994329576923690768489;
```

**Manually formatting?**

Below hints that OP is not using an auto formatter.  Code looks nice.  Yet I would rather oblige a SW team to use auto formatting that spend time formatting.

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                      HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                      LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                      int       nCmdShow)
```

Save time and increase productivity: auto-format.

**Comment units**

Naked code like `const int SLEEP_DURATION = 2500 / 360;` lacks units.  How long is 2500? 2500 seconds, 2500 milliseconds?  Do not lay the seeds for another [big bucks units failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure).

```
// const int SLEEP_DURATION = 2500 / 360;
const int SLEEP_DURATION = 2500 /* ms */ / 360;
```

**Truncated quotient?**

Note that `2500 / 360.0` is 6.9444... and `2500 / 360` is 6.  Code may want to do things more precisely.  At a minimum, consider a *rounded* quotient.

```
// const int SLEEP_DURATION = 2500 / 360;
const int SLEEP_DURATION = (2500 + 360/2) / 360;
```

Answer (score 1):

continuing the item about the timer constant

```
const int SLEEP_DURATION = 2500 / 360;
```

I would do

```
const int RUN_TIME = 2500; // ms = 2.5 seconds
const int DEGREES_IN_CIRCLE; = 360
const int SLEEP_TIME = RUN_TIME / DEGREES_IN_CIRCLE;
```

and

```
for (int degree = 0; degree < DEGREES_IN_CIRLCE; degree++, currentDegree++)
```

never have magic numbers except maybe 0,1 and possibly 2 :-)

BTW +1 for const not #define